# fetch path based upon relationship propertty in NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find all those nodes that are connected to specific node based upon certain relationship label. This is what I have got so far,

```
Match (n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[:NDFRT {RelationLabel : "RO_may_be_treated_by"}]-> (m:UMLSConcepts) RETURN (n), (m)
```

where (n) is a specific node and (m) are all other nodes that are connected with this node. Problem with above statement is that it is dependent upon a specific relation type in this case(NDFRT), but I want all relation type that contains certain relationship properties in this case("RO_may_be_treated_by") because there could be path/edge in other relation type as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I I fully understood your question, you can simply omit the relationship type in your Cypher query, this way:

```
Match (n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[{RelationLabel : "RO_may_be_treated_by"}]-> (m:UMLSConcepts)
RETURN (n), (m)
```

Comment: could you please provide a query that  gets indirect path between those nodes as well, because above query gets me only direct paths

Comment: @gaurav1207 you can simply omit the relationship direction too. This way: `Match (n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[{RelationLabel : "RO_may_be_treated_by"}]-(m:UMLSConcepts)
RETURN (n), (m)`

Comment: I did this Match p = (n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[r]- (m) 
where r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat" 
RETURN p, but it still fetches direct paths

Comment: @gaurav1207 Weird. Your query should return all paths regardless of direction. Maybe you should make a new question explaining a bit more about your data set.

Comment: If you're looking for a path from `n` to `m` connected by relationships with that property, then you'll need to use [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) in the pattern: `(n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[{RelationLabel : "RO_may_be_treated_by"}*]-(m:UMLSConcepts) RETURN (n), (m)`

Comment: @InverseFalcon This shows an incorrect syntax on browser UI

Comment: @gaurav1207 So it does. I had the `*` on the wrong side of the properties. Try this: `MATCH (n:UMLSConcepts{ConceptID: 'C3254924'})-[*{RelationLabel : "RO_may_be_treated_by"}]-(m:UMLSConcepts) RETURN (n), (m)`